# Evaluating the triple integral $\int_0^{\pi}\int_x^{\pi}\int_0^2\frac{\sin y}{y}dzdydx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do we evaluate the triple integral
$$\int_0^{\pi}\int_x^{\pi}\int_0^2\frac{\sin y}{y}dzdydx$$

I am totally struck at this easy looking problem. How do we change the orders so that the $y$ term in the denominator cancels out after integration? The second limits contain $x$ term. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The innermost integral is trivial.

Comment: @random yes, but the very next integral does not have representation in elementary functions, if we proceed with the given order

Answer (score 7):

First of all integrate in $z$:
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\int_x^{\pi}\int_0^2\frac{\sin y}{y}\,dzdydx=2\int_0^{\pi}\int_x^{\pi}\frac{\sin y}{y}\,dydx.
$$
For each fixed $x\in[0,\pi]$ $y$ moves between $x$ and $\pi$. The region of integration is a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,\pi)$ and $(\pi,\pi)$. Changing the order of of integration, for each $y\in[0,\pi]$, $x$ moves between $0$ and $y$. The integral becomes
$$
2\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{y}\frac{\sin y}{y}\,dxdy,
$$
which is now easy to compute.

I strongly recommend to draw a picture of the region of integration to see what is going on.

Comment: thanks! I just got it. It was so easy